# R looping with text to call different datasets

Tags: r, loops

I want to create similar radar plots from numerous country "data sets" and title each chart accordingly. Can someone help me get the loop right where R recognizes my dataframe? The error I get is:

**> Error in is.data.frame(df) : object 'data_i' not found**

**Code:**

```
    data_China=rbind(rep(100,1) , rep(1,100) , data)      
    data_Indonesia=rbind(rep(100,1) , rep(1,100) , data)
    data_India=rbind(rep(100,1) , rep(1,100) , data)
    data_Kenya=rbind(rep(100,1) , rep(1,100) , data)

    par(mfrow=c(2,2),mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1))

clist <- c("Indonesia", "China", "India", "Kenya")

for (i in clist) {
    # Custom the radarChart !
    radarchart(data_i  , axistype=1 , 

                #custom polygon
                pcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9) , pfcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5) , plwd=4 , 

                #custom the grid
                cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="black", caxislabels=seq(0,100,20), cglwd=0.8,

                #custom labels
                vlcex=0.6 , title="i"
    )
    }
```

Comment: What is `data` in your multiple calls of `rbind()` ? + Are you sure that `data_i` is available as variable ?

Comment: @MbrMbr I think OP is attempting to concatenate `data_` and the value from `i` ("Indonesia" for example) to call `data_Indonesia`.

Answer (score 1):

You can place all the datasets into a list, and iterate over that:

```
dataList <- list(China = data_China, 
                 Indonesia = data_Indonesia, 
                 India = data_India, 
                 Kenya = data_Kenya)

for (i in 1:length(dataList)) {
radarchart(dataList[[i]] , axistype=1 , 

            #custom polygon
            pcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9) , pfcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5) , plwd=4 , 

            #custom the grid
            cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="black", caxislabels=seq(0,100,20), cglwd=0.8,

            #custom labels
            vlcex=0.6 , title=names(dataList)[i]
)
}
```